# Dividing AVG of column1 by AVG of column2

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to divide the average value of column1 by the average value of column 2, which will give me an average price from my data. I believe there is a problem with my syntax / structure of my code, or I am making a rookie mistake.

I have searched stack and cannot find many examples of dividing two averaged columns, and checked the postgres documentation.

The individual average query is working fine (as shown here)
`SELECT (AVG(CAST("Column1" AS numeric(4,2))),2) FROM table1`

But when I combine two of them in an attempt to divide, It simply does not work.

`SELECT (AVG(CAST("Column1" AS numeric(4,2))),2) / (AVG(CAST("Column2" AS numeric(4,2))),2) FROM table1`

I am receiving the following error; "ERROR:  row comparison operator must yield type boolean, not type numeric". I have tried a few other variations which have mostly given me syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do with your current approach.  However, if you want to take the ratio of two averages, you could also just take the ratio of the sums:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Column1 AS numeric(4,2))) / SUM(CAST(Column2 AS numeric(4,2)))
FROM table1;
```

Note that `SUM()` just takes a single input, not two inputs.  The reason why we can use the sums is that average would normalize both the numerator and denominator by the same amount, which is the number of rows in `table1`.  Hence, this factor just cancels out.

Comment: Thank you! It gave me the result I was looking for.

Comment: Please be aware that this only works if the columns are full of data. If there are any `NULL` values (especially if there are significantly more `NULL` values in one of the columns) you have to either exclude those rows completely or adjust your expression accordingly.

Comment: @Cornholio Not really.  `SUM` ignores `NULL` values, so the only problem would be if every record were `NULL`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: But if there is a different amount of `NULL` values in both columns, the avg calculation would need to be normalized by different values and you can't just use the SUM anymore